# [self.view addSubview:myView.view]; strange behavior

Tags: ios

I start working on a project with ios 5 and xcode 4.3, according to requirement updated to ios6 and xcode 4.5. After this I created new viewcontroller with .h, .m, .xib file and tried to add in my existing view as a subview with these steps

- #import the class
- created the property of it with (strong, nonatomic)
- @synthesize it
- myView = [[MYView alloc]init]
- finally [self.view addSubview:myView.view]

all project including this working fine in ios 6 but only this new view that I am trying to add as a subview is crasing in ios 5 and getting this error `Thread 1: signal SIGTRAP`. I try to debug step by step but as the addsubview executes app crashes. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: but why its working in ios 6, other subview that are added same way before updating to ios6 also working on both ios5 & ios6

Comment: Just to confirm, instead of [self.view addSubview:myView.view] do you mean [self.view addSubview:myView]?

Comment: @Sweet Jenny if my suspection is right, and this is a memory management problem, then your app basically invokes UB which means anything can happen, including it working "correctly" or crashing.

Comment: @Dick its [self.view addSubview:myView.view]

Comment: @H2CO3 but every time its working fine on ios6 and every time its crasing on ios5

Comment: @SweetJenny Yes, I understand that.

Comment: @SweetJenny Does it crush on device or emulator?

Comment: It's still unclear to me why you're adding myView.view instead of just myView assuming that MYView is a subclass of UIView. Anyway, did you try using the Zombie profiler? That should give you an idea if there is an overrelease issue.

Comment: it crashs on device didnt check on simulator

Comment: @Dick myView is a subclass of UIViewController thats why I am doing myView.view

Comment: Do you manipulate your custom view on another thread by any chance ?

Comment: @giorashc no didnt do anything like that

Comment: Than how do you initialize you custom controller's view member ?

Comment: hmmm, can you also provide more context on what you are trying to achieve? Nesting view controllers is typically not a good idea; as of iOS 5 you can / need to use container view controllers so that the view lifecycle is properly taken care of.

Comment: this is init method - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: and all custom controller's member are hooked through xib file

Comment: @Dick myview is a audio recording view in which user can rec there voices and on finishing the audio data is passed to main viewcontroller, add all is working fine, perfectly on ios 6 but the only problem is ios5

Comment: I also try [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES]; but still same error of signal SIGTRAP

Comment: no buddy got any solution ... ?

Answer (score 0):

it should be [self.view addSubview:myView];

and also, you created a property for view, you don't need to make an allocation.
myView = [[MYView alloc]init]

memory allocation will make your app crash.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its Autolayout which was causing the problem